# FFMPEG -codec copy creates incorrect duration when edit atoms are in input

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

When using FFMPEG to `-codec copy` an input with [Edit Atoms](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH204-25579) before transcoding, the resulting output contains incorrect durations.

[mp4dump](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4dump/) reveals a list of edit atoms for this [example mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ql7BCz-EqCEBAxQ1G1nxfT8CWt_SogF3/view?usp=sharing) on the audio track.

```
...
    [edts] size=8+52
      [elst] size=12+40
        entry count = 3
        entry/segment duration = 111968
        entry/media time = 0
        entry/media rate = 1
        entry/segment duration = 111968
        entry/media time = 322560
        entry/media rate = 1
        entry/segment duration = 111968
        entry/media time = 645120
        entry/media rate = 1
...
```

using `ffmpeg version 4.1.3` and running

```sh
ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -codec copy example-copy.ts
```

and then running

```sh
ffmpeg -i example-copy.ts example-out.mp4
```

produces an output with a different duration than the input introducing A/V sync issues

input audio stream duration=21.868776

output audio stream duration=23.821769

The issue does not occur when skipping the `-codec copy` step and going straight to the transcode step (but this step is currently an important part of our workflow).

The issue also doesn't occur (for this example) when `-codec copy`ing to a different video container, like [.nut](https://ffmpeg.org/nut.html), but in other examples (specifically ones with a single edit atom entry with > 0 media_time) changing the video container doesn't solve the issue.

**Is FFMPEG ignoring/dropping the edit list when using the codec copy operation?**

**Is this the expected behavior or is there and issue with FFMPEG?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with packet demuxing and timestamp modification that ffmpeg maintains when demuxing.

```
pts_time=6.269388|dts=276480|duration=1024|pos=460238
pts_time=6.292608|dts=277504|duration=1024|pos=460529   <---
pts_time=6.315828|dts=278528|duration=1024|pos=460813
pts_time=6.339048|dts=279552|duration=1024|pos=461094
pts_time=6.362268|dts=280576|duration=1024|pos=461379
pts_time=6.385488|dts=281600|duration=1024|pos=461659
pts_time=6.408707|dts=282624|duration=1024|pos=461941
pts_time=6.431927|dts=283648|duration=1024|pos=462217
pts_time=6.455147|dts=284672|duration=1024|pos=462498
pts_time=6.478367|dts=285696|duration=1024|pos=462782
pts_time=6.501587|dts=286720|duration=1024|pos=497050
pts_time=6.524807|dts=287744|duration=1024|pos=497316
pts_time=6.548027|dts=288768|duration=1024|pos=497552
pts_time=6.571247|dts=289792|duration=1024|pos=497562
pts_time=6.594467|dts=290816|duration=1024|pos=497648
pts_time=6.617687|dts=291840|duration=1024|pos=497927
pts_time=6.640907|dts=292864|duration=1024|pos=498205
pts_time=6.664127|dts=293888|duration=1024|pos=498484
pts_time=6.687347|dts=294912|duration=1024|pos=498763
pts_time=6.710567|dts=295936|duration=1024|pos=499041
pts_time=6.733787|dts=296960|duration=1024|pos=499320
pts_time=6.757007|dts=297984|duration=1024|pos=499599
pts_time=6.780227|dts=299008|duration=1024|pos=499877
pts_time=6.803447|dts=300032|duration=1024|pos=500156
pts_time=6.826667|dts=301056|duration=1024|pos=500434
pts_time=6.849887|dts=302080|duration=1024|pos=500713
pts_time=6.873107|dts=303104|duration=1024|pos=500992
pts_time=6.896327|dts=304128|duration=1024|pos=501270
pts_time=6.919546|dts=305152|duration=1024|pos=501549
pts_time=6.942766|dts=306176|duration=1024|pos=501828
pts_time=6.965986|dts=307200|duration=1024|pos=502106
pts_time=6.989206|dts=308224|duration=1024|pos=502385
pts_time=7.012426|dts=309248|duration=1024|pos=584916
pts_time=7.035646|dts=310272|duration=1024|pos=585194
pts_time=7.058866|dts=311296|duration=1024|pos=585473
pts_time=7.082086|dts=312320|duration=1024|pos=585930
pts_time=7.105306|dts=313344|duration=1024|pos=586295
pts_time=7.128526|dts=314368|duration=1024|pos=586659
pts_time=7.151746|dts=315392|duration=1024|pos=586999
pts_time=7.174966|dts=316416|duration=1024|pos=587280
pts_time=7.198186|dts=317440|duration=1024|pos=587569
pts_time=7.221406|dts=318464|duration=1024|pos=587859
pts_time=7.244626|dts=319488|duration=1024|pos=588145
pts_time=7.267846|dts=320512|duration=1024|pos=588425
pts_time=6.267914|dts=276415|duration=1024|pos=460529   <---
pts_time=6.291134|dts=277439|duration=1024|pos=460813
pts_time=6.314354|dts=278463|duration=1024|pos=461094
```

Using this for the first step

```
ffmpeg -advanced_editlist 0 -i example.mp4 -codec copy example-copy.ts
```

produces a transcoded MP4 that plays in sync for me.

Consider opening a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org.

Comment: Im experiencing this as well

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar problem but with an mkv file. I am trying to copy a 1 minute audio clip from a video+audio mkv file, and getting a 1:10 result. As far as I can understand, the -advanced_editlist option is for the mp4 demuxer, so I checked the matroska demuxer for available options but didn't find anything similar. Do you know what the problem could be? Also, this happens when using -ss to get an offset.